# php: quickest way to generate a 5-digit number not already in MySQL db column (with a unique attribute)

Tags: php, mysql, random, numbers

Suppose Table1 contains column orderid (not a key, although it's NOT NULL and unique). It contains 5-digit numbers. 
What's the best way to generate a php var $unique_var that is not in that column.
What could be important, from 10% to 30% of 5-digit numbers are in the table (so generating a number and checking `while (mysql_num_rows() ==0) {}` is not a best way to find one, are there any better solution for performance?).

Thank you.

Comment: I know it might not be what you want, but you could define your key column as an auto_increment column and set the start value for auto_increment to be 10,000. You then have until 100,000 worth of numbers, and the database will do all the work for you when you add a new row. I am assuming you don't consider 09999 or less to be a 5 digit number for your purposes though

Comment: is there any special reason you want to generate the number in PHP?

Comment: it's like an orderid - should not just be as 1,2,3, but should also contain some more information like a control check sum (kind of the number 39113 says the number is correct, because 3+9+1=13 - the last two numbers, and the number has no mistakes or has at least two mistakes). So, when a person tells you 39113, you are pretty sure he told you a correct orderid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is *just* 10-30% of numbers already taken - then it means that *only* 10-30% of queries will be performed at least twice. Which is not a big performance issue at all.

Otherwise - just create all-5-digit-numbers-list table (just 100k rows) and remove all that exist. When you need another random number - just pick one and delete.

Comment: Thank you. I think the pitfall using this method is that two the same 5-digit numbers could be generated (before the first one was inserted into the table). One will be inserted, another one will be failed. Still don't know if any better way exists...

Comment: @Haradzieniec: with separated table that keeps list of unused yet numbers you will not ever get a conflict (as long as you lock row or the whole table)

Comment: I'm sorry... Could you please explain what do you mean when you say to lock row or the whole table? InnoDB is the default Engine if that's important. Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec: create the table with 00001..99999 numbers and delete all the values already used. When you need another number - lock the table, pick one number, delete it, unlock the table.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest finding the biggest number (with a MAX() clause) and start from there.

Comment: That won't work as the numbers are from 00001 to 99999 (it's limited by 99999). The number of that unique numbers never exceeds the number of 5-digit numbers, even 30% of 5-digit numbers, but unfortunately this method won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of suggestions. Each has its drawbacks.

1. Pre-populate your table and add a column to indicate that a number is unused. Select an unused number using `LIMIT = 1` and mark it used. This uses a lot of space.
2. Keep a separate table containing previously used numbers. If that table is empty, generate numbers sequentially from the last used number (or from 00001 if Table1 is empty). This requires some extra bookkeeping.